# JavaScript regex with escaped slashes does not replace

Tags: javascript, regex, escaping

Do i have to escape slashes when putting them into regular expression?

```
myString = '/courses/test/user';
myString.replace(/\/courses\/([^\/]*)\/.*/, "$1");
document.write(myString);
```

Instead of printing "test", it prints the whole source string.

See this demo:

http://jsbin.com/esaro3/2/edit

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Your regex is perfect, and yes, you must escape slashes since JavaScript uses the slashes to indicate regexes.

However, the problem is that JavaScript's `replace` method does not perform an in-place replace. That is, it does not actually change the string -- it just gives you the result of the replace.

Try this:

```
myString = '/courses/test/user';
myString = myString.replace(/\/courses\/([^\/]*)\/.*/, "$1");
document.write(myString);
```

This sets `myString` to the replaced value.

Answer (score 21):

`/[\/]/g` matches forward slashes.
`/[\\]/g` matches backward slashes.

Comment: And `/[\/|\\]/g` match both forward and backward slashes.

Comment: @NikSumeiko it matches `|` too. For matching *only* backslashes and forward slashes use either `/[\/\\]/` or ``/\/|\\/``.

Answer (score 14):

Actually, you don't need to escape the slash when inside a character class as in one part of your example (i.e., `[^\/]*` is fine as just `[^/]*`). If it is outside of a character class (like with the rest of your example such as `\/courses`), then you do need to escape slashes.

Answer (score 9):

`string.replace` doesn't modify the original string. Instead, a returns a new string that has had the replacement performed.

Try:

```
myString = '/courses/test/user';
document.write(myString.replace(/\/courses\/([^\/]*)\/.*/, "$1"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Note, that you don't have to escape `/` if you use `new RegExp()` constructor:

```js
console.log(new RegExp("a/b").test("a/b"))
```