# Need to test JS regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

When I type in my input the text appears on image. I want to make the code work like that:

When user types character that is recognized by regex then place it on image else just throw some error or do not let it type at all in the input field.

This is the regex: `[A-Z0-9a-z&,.-/()@*+!?"':; -]`

I'm trying to achieve it like this:

```
$("#firstText").keyup(function () {
  var value = $(this).val().toUpperCase();
  var regex = "[A-Z0-9a-z&,.-/()@*+!?"':; -]";

  if(regex.test(value))
  {
    $(".zetin16").text(value);
  } else {
    alert('this is bad');
  }
});
```

But I get this error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

In this line: `var regex = "[A-Z0-9a-z&,.-/()@*+!?"':; -]";`

Thanks in advance for any help.

**UPDATE**

The regex working fine now. Now I want to prevent typing characters in input when regex doesnt match the character. This is my code currently:

```
$("#firstText").keyup(function(e) {
    var value = $(this).val().toUpperCase();
    var regex = new RegExp(/[A-Z0-9a-z&,.-/()@*+!?"':; -]/);

    if (regex.test(value)) {
        $(".zetin16").text(value);
    } else {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: You've got a double quote inside your string which is terminating it early. Syntax highlighting is your friend here.

Comment: first change regex like this
var regex = "[A-Z0-9a-z&,.-/()@*+!?:; -]";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact error you're seeing is because you are defining the variable as a double quoted string, with an unescaped double quote in it.

It shouldn't be a string anyway. It should be a regular expression like this.

```
var regex = /[A-Z0-9a-z&,.-/()@*+!?"':; -]/;
```

Comment: Okay I dont get any error now. But is there are some function that prevents typing characters that are not available by regex ? :)

Comment: @feknuolis [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995183/how-to-allow-only-numeric-0-9-in-html-inputbox-using-jquery) could help.

Comment: @feknuolis or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19111723/1479535)

Answer (score 2):

With regex, use the forward slash as delimiter. If a forward slash occurs as a literal inside the regex itself, escape it:

```
var regex = /[A-Z0-9a-z&,.-\/()@*+!?"':; -]/;
```

Reference: [JavaScript regex replace - escaping slashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674237/javascript-regex-replace-escaping-slashes)

(The problem with the original string was that it contained a double quote, and was delimited using double quotes at the same time).

Answer (score 0):

try using this pattern for using regular expression

```
var regex = "['A-Z0-9a-z&,.-/()@*+!?':; -]";

var reg =new RegExp(regex)

var val ="asss"

reg.test(val)
```