# How to use {{ }} in Javascript regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to verify this pattern:

> {{ a valid variable name }}

Something like this:

```
/{{aaaa}}     ---> matches
/{{a}}        ---> matches
/{{a1a}}      ---> matches
/             ---> matches
/{aaa}}       ---> no matches
/{aaa}        ---> no matches
/{{aaa}       ---> no matches
/aaa}}        ---> no matches
/{{aaa        ---> no matches
```

and so forth...

I have this pattern:

```
^\\/(({){2}[A-Za-z0-9]+(}){2})*$
```

According to https://www.debuggex.com/#cheatsheet it is well written, but it doesn't work. Any suggestion on how to solve this?

Comment: What does it mean by "it doesn't work"? Which tests does it fail?

Comment: `^\{{2}[\w]+\}{2}$` can you please try this

Comment: It is not a good practice to downvote without saying why. Also, this question has nothing to do with the suggested https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674237/javascript-regex-with-escaped-slashes-does-not-replace, completely different questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the start, you need to escape the `/` correctly:

```
^\/(({){2}[A-Za-z0-9]+(}){2})*$
 ^
```

Also, this can be simplified by removing the `{2}`:

```
^\/(({{)[A-Za-z0-9]+(}}))*$
```